# How to edit the labels of a facet_wrap/grid if there are two variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot I have faceted by two variables (`tau` and `z`) but can only change the label of the first:

```
df<-data.frame(x=runif(1e3),y=runif(1e3),tau=rep(c("A","aBc"),each=500),z=rep(c("DDD","EEE"),each=500))

tauNames <- c(
  `A` = "10% load",
  `aBc` = "40% load"
)



df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.4)+
  xlab(label = "Time[s]")+
  ylab(label = "Dose")+
  facet_grid(tau~z,labeller = as_labeller(tauNames))+
  ggpubr::theme_pubclean()
```

[image]

As you can see I can change one of the labels but not both. Any thoughts are much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of `?as_labeller` you can find in the examples how you get the labels for multiple faceting variables.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df<-data.frame(x=runif(1e3),y=runif(1e3),tau=rep(c("A","aBc"),each=500),z=rep(c("DDD","EEE"),each=500))

tauNames <- c(
  `A` = "10% load",
  `aBc` = "40% load"
)

df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(alpha=0.4)+
  xlab(label = "Time[s]")+
  ylab(label = "Dose")+
  facet_grid(tau~z,labeller = labeller(tau = tauNames, 
                                       z = c("DDD" = "D", "EEE" = "E")))+
  ggpubr::theme_pubclean()
```

[image]